# Can you wait and then perform an en passant capture?

Tags: en-passant

I am new to chess, so sorry for this obvious question. I was surfing through the web and learned the en passant rule. In [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5662/when-is-it-possible-to-carry-out-the-en-passant-manoeuvre) they say "You cannot wait a few moves and then use the en passant capture." So I went searching through websites to find out if I can wait, then play the en passant capture and found nothing. So what I want to know is, if for example there are 2 pawns by each other, can I wait and play a few moves and then perform the move. Example: (I know the image below can't happen, but just saying.)

[image]

And then play a few moves like shown below.

[image]

And finally capture the white piece using en passant.

Comment: Welcome to [chess.se]! Carefully reading the first two answers in the linked question will clear up your doubt, so I've marked this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Not relevant to the en passant question, but I just wanted to note that the first position you show actually _can_ happen. 1.Nf3 e5 2.Ng1 e4 3.d4 and then Black can capture en passant.

Comment: This question is easily answered using Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En-passant can only occur *immediately* after a pawn moves two squares from its starting square, where it could have been captured had it only moved one square.

You cannot wait a move: if you choose not to immediately capture en-passant, you lose the ability to do so next move.